# To run GEE vs Multi-level (mixed) Effect model for repeated measures analysis on ordinal outcome

Tags: repeated-measures

I am fairly new when it comes to R, so please bare with me.

My question is: I have data from 92 patients (154 eyes; I have data from both eyes of some subjects versus only one eye for others). My outcome of interest is on ordinal scale. Everyone in this study underwent a particular surgery of interest, and we want to determine whether this surgery worsened an eye symptom (the outcome on the ordinal scale).

The outcome is measured at three time points (1 = 2 months prior to surgery, 2 = 1 week post surgery, and 3 = 2 months post surgery).

I was thinking of running GEE in R using the multgee function (specifically, ordLORgee), but I was reading a little more and was wondering if I should run a multilevel mixed effect model instead?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The GEE requires fewer assumptions. And if you are interesting in keeping your model as close to OLS as possible, then it is the way to go, as your fixed effects are population-averaged. Your sample size of 92 seems large enough not to be a problem.

If you want to model cluster specific features, understand the decomposition of variance, then you should use a mixed-effects model. McNeish and Stapleton (2017) provide a good comparison of these methods.

Here's the best approach if you have the time. Run both methods, and see the differences in the results. There is always something to be gained from doing this. In the paper below, the authors state that both methods can lead to different conclusions especially with discrete outcomes.

---

Mcneish, D., Stapleton, L. M., & Silverman, R. D. (2017). On the Unnecessary Ubiquity of Hierarchical Linear Modeling. *Psychological Methods, 22*(1), 114–140. https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000078